# Does passing an aggregate object instead of a long argument list of objects reduce data coupling

Tags: code-metrics, coupling

I read that data coupling can be reduced by "not passing unnecessary arguments"

Say there is a `makeCake` method which requires many instance variables in the `Ingredients` class as parameters:

```
 makeCake(ingredients.flour, ingredients.egg, ingredients.sugar, ingredients.cheese, ingredients.cream)
```

And instead of this, just pass the whole Ingredients Object

```
 makeCake(ingredients)
```

and access the variables within the `makeCake` method..

---

Is this counted as reducing coupling between the class which calls the makeCake method and the Ingredients class? Before you were passing 5 arguments and now you're only passing one?

(Note that this question was made with the Java language - and the OO side of Scala - in mind)

(sorry if this question is making you crave cake, it was the first thing that popped into my head) :)

Comment: In your first example you actually pass the values of the ingredients attributes (flour, egg, etc.). Therefore there is no coupling between makeCake and ingredients. In your second example you pass the ingredients itself. Here you get a coupling between makeCake and ingredients.

Comment: I see.. I'm new to the whole coupling concept and might be wrong. I thought coupling was between classes/objects? So the coupling would be between **the class** with the makeCake method and the Ingredients class?

Comment: I think wolfrevo's comment actually the right answer

Comment: To check if your class is coupled to another, remove the dependent class and see if the compiler complaints increases or decreases :-)

Comment: @user3120842 Concepts like coupling or dependency are allways related to the programming language you use. And such concepts are defined in the context of the language. For instance you could read this chapter of DepFinder (http://depfind.sourceforge.net/Manual.html#Dependencies). DepFinder is a code metrics tool for Java

Comment: Thanks wolfrevo.. I'm thinking of Java when I made the question.. will add this to the question description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see http://depfind.sourceforge.net/Manual.html#Dependencies:

> ... a dependency is when the functioning of one element A requires the
>   presence of another element B. We say that A *depends* on B and we write
>   it:
>
> ```
> A --> B
> ```
>
> We say that A has an *outbound* dependency while B has an *inbound*
>   dependency. It is the same dependency, but whether it is inbound or
>   outbound is relative to how you look at it. We also say that A is a
>   *dependent* and B is *dependable*.
>
> A dependency graph comprises nodes for software artifacts linked
>   together using two types of relationships.
>
> Artifacts are packages, classes, and features. We use the term *feature*
>   to designate class attributes, constructors, and methods; we will be
>   treating them the same from here on. For the purpose of analyzing
>   dependencies, we do not distinguish between different types of
>   features, whether they are constructors or regular methods, and
>   regardless of the feature's characteristics, such as being marked as
>   final or static.
>
> The first type of relationship is *composition*. Packages have classes,
>   which themselves have features. We call this kind of "has a"
>   relationship *composition*. A feature node is linked to its class node
>   through composition. A class node is also linked to its package node
>   through composition.
>
> The second type of relationship is *dependency*. Classes refer to each
>   other, features refer to each other, and features refer to classes. We
>   call this kind of relationship *dependency*. Each node is linked to
>   various other nodes of various type using dependency links.

Answer (score 0):

I think not so much.

I think a change in the format is not the idea.

Rather, if you passed an "ingredients id" and let the target look up what it needed....that would be less coupled.

Comment: although passing the whole object would accomplish a similar goal... I might change my mind :)

Comment: Not really, all thst does is to add yet another dependency on the lookup provider.