# Coupling and dependencies clarification

Tags: java, dependencies, coupling

I'm currently learning about coupling and dependencies in Java. I've been reading [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/ood/understanding-dependencies.html) and understand that if class1 contains an instance of class2 and if you call a method like `exampleMethod(c2)`, this counts as dependency between class1 and class2. However, I am unsure about the examples below. Can anyone give me some clarification?

Assuming that we are inside class1 (which contains class2 `c2`):

1. If class1 calls a method defined in class2 (`c2.aMethod()` for example), does this count as a dependency/coupling between class1 and class2?
2. Does calling `c2.someSetterMethod(argument)` count as dependency/coupling between class1 and class2?
3. Does calling `c2.repaint()` within class1 count as a dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that class1 contains a reference to an instance of class2 suffices to say that class1 *depends* on class2. In all of your 3 examples you need a reference to class2 in order to call its methods. This only increases the need for dependency in your class1 but not the dependency itself.

Please read http://depfind.sourceforge.net/Manual.html#Dependencies as mentioned in my answer to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21689495/1659599.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. Yes.
3. Yes.

One way to reduce coupling is to use interfaces. This way, class 1 only knows about the interface, and is not coupled with class 2 specifically. And in fact, any class that implements the interface could be used instead of class 2 and class 1 would still be satisfied.